# Loadash Debounce Vuejs with Buefy Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

I'm using Vuejs cdn with buefy, axios and loadash, I'm trying to use _.debounce so I wont call an API too many time with the Buefy Autocomplete with a query that I send, I've got it working but the autocomplete is not showing the results as when I don't use debounce, so my sections are as follow:

Autocomplete Html:

```
<b-autocomplete
   v-model="AirportDestinationName"
   :data="airports"
   placeholder="Ciudad de destino"
   field="code"
   icon="map-marker-alt"
   :loading="isFetching"
   @input="getAsyncData(AirportDestinationName)"
   @select="option => AirportDestinationSelected = option">
       <template slot-scope="props">
       <strong>(@{{ props.option.code }})</strong> - @{{props.option.name}} - 
       @{{props.option.country_name}}
       </template>
</b-autocomplete>
```

My Method without debounce which is working:

```
getAsyncData(query) {
      if(query.length>1){
            this.airports = []
            this.isFetching = true
                axios.get(`https://iatacodes.org/api/v6/autocomplete?api_key=xxxxxxxxsomekeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&query=${query}`)
                    .then(data => {
                        data.data.response.airports.forEach((item) => this.airports.push(item))
                        this.isFetching = false
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.isFetching = false
                        throw error
                    })
              }


        }
```

Then I hace a funcion with debounce, but when I use it replacing the other funcion, the autocomplete is not generating the dropdown, it's weird because the example is the same as I'm using:

```
GotoDeb: _.debounce((query)=>{
                console.log(query)
                this.airports = []
                this.isFetching = true
                    axios.get(`https://iatacodes.org/api/v6/autocomplete?api_key=xxxxxxxxsomekeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&query=${query}`)
                        .then(data => {
                            data.data.response.airports.forEach((item) => this.airports.push(item))
                            this.isFetching = false
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.isFetching = false
                            throw error
                        })
                console.log(this.airports)
                console.log('fetched')
              },500)
```

Everything else is working and I'm not getting any error from the server nor the client, even when I console.log the airports fetched from the API, there they are, the axios function worked!

**EDIT:**
The problem was on the arrow function that I was using, when you use an `()=>` the `this` that you usaually use won't stay, instead, `this` becomes only from that new function.

Comment: Try using `function` instead of an arrow function (`=>`). You may have a `this` problem.

Comment: I DO have a `this` problem, I thought about it like 30min after finally posting this (which took me a while). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with ***@input="getAsyncData(AirportDestinationName)"*** line.
it should be ***@input="getAsyncData*** only.

Just an example:

```
private getAsyncData = _.debounce((query)=>{
                console.log(query)
                this.airports = []
                this.isFetching = true
                    axios.get(`https://iatacodes.org/api/v6/autocomplete?api_key=xxxxxxxxsomekeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&query=${query}`)
                        .then(data => {
                            data.data.response.airports.forEach((item) => this.airports.push(item))
                            this.isFetching = false
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.isFetching = false
                            throw error
                        })
                console.log(this.airports)
                console.log('fetched')
              },500);
```

Comment: But how do I send the data from the input to the function so I can use it in tue 'query' variable?